Augmentation for numeric small dataset
I have a dataset that is very small and for this reason it performs very poorly (65,20). How can I enlarge the dataset?  I multiplied the dataset by a series of numbers and entered it into the main dataset (about 7 times), the performance of the models improved, but the dataset is not normal, no matter how much I put in the scaler.  Does anyone know what to do?

What kind of dataset is it? How have you tried to augment it? What do you mean by 'performs very poorly (65,20)' ?

@MuhammedYunus
I tried this method but it not change my volume data and model didn't improved.

@picky_porpoise
dataset is numeric and tabular. dimensions of the data set is 65 * 28.

@ErfanMollai You might be able to train even with these few samples, using the right strategy. I could take a look if you were able to upload a sample or email it.

@MuhammedYunus
how can i email it for you?

@MuhammedYunus
I'm so sorry but it not work me :(
